# bluetooth dongle not powered when plugged, only at boot

Tags: arch-linux, usb, bluetooth, bluez

When executing `sudo hcitool lescan` I get:

```
Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error
```

Executing `bluetoothctl` and using the `show` command targetting the dongle's controller I noticed it's "Powered: no". Powering it on makes `sudo hcitool lescan` work as expected.

I'm on ArchLinux with the following bluetooth stack:

```
~ ❯❯❯ pacman -Qs bluetooth
extra/bluez 5.43-2
    Daemons for the bluetooth protocol stack
extra/bluez-firmware 1.2-8
    Firmwares for Broadcom BCM203x and STLC2300 Bluetooth chips
extra/bluez-libs 5.43-2
    Deprecated libraries for the bluetooth protocol stack
extra/bluez-utils 5.43-2
    Development and debugging utilities for the bluetooth protocol stack
extra/gnome-bluetooth 3.20.0+6+g3bac4f9-1
    The GNOME Bluetooth Subsystem
extra/pulseaudio-bluetooth 10.0-2
    Bluetooth support for PulseAudio
community/python2-pybluez 0.22-2
    Python wrapper for the BlueZ Bluetooth stack
extra/sbc 1.3-1
    Bluetooth Subband Codec (SBC) library
```

Is there a way to fix plug & play and make the bluetooth controller powered when it gets plugged? (if I let it plugged, it works as expected after boot, without disconnecting)

[image: power controller on]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate the bluetoothctl program to power on the device for you when it is connected to the computer.

A better option is to use something more easily scriptable. Bluetoothctl requires you echo commands to stdin, a little strange.

A udev rule to detect the device being plugged in should be able to handle this.

<sub>Please note, that on machines with built-in bluetooth radios, it's very likely that `hci0` would refer not to the external blueotoh dongle, but instead to the built-in one.</sub>



<sup>In cases like that, substitute `hci0` with `hci1` in the following file contents.</sup>

Create this file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules`

Contents:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="hci0", RUN+="/usr/bin/hciconfig %k up"
```

---

If that dosn't work, you can try scripting bluetoothctl instead.

The udev rule would look something like this:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="hci0", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/PowerOnBluetooth"
```

Create this file: `/usr/local/bin/PowerOnBluetooth`

Contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e 'power on\nquit\n' | bluetoothctl
```

Don't forget to mark the file executable:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/PowerOnBluetooth
```

---

Sources:

[ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#bluetoothctl_2)

[Archlinux user with same problem](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=171144)

Comment: `/power/control` for the device is `auto` on connect, changing to `on` didn't produce any effect, and when unplugging/plugging it, it resets to `auto`.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your problem. How exactly do you power on the device when it is in the state "Powered: no"?

Comment: Oh and also, show the lsusb output for the device as well.

Comment: I power it from `bluetoothctl` console, I just type `power on`. `lsusb`: http://i.imgur.com/aI7TBV0.png.

Comment: Notice that "`Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error`" is quite easy to find on google, most questions with no answer accepted, and I figured to `power on` through `bluetoothctl` by myself, and it works, although annoying. Answers provided in other QAs didn't help at all.

Comment: I've updated the question with another screenshot.

Comment: can you try this command? `sudo bccmd psread` It should show if there's a setting we can change.

Comment: Output to the command is solely "Unsupported manufacturer".

Comment: Ah ok. I figured it out. Editing answer now.

Comment: Thanks, this should be an acceptable answer once I test it. Sadly, I expected to be another way besides an udev rule =/ like some fix b/c the way it's now it's simply broken plug & play, it should be working out of the box.

Comment: by the way, I have tried `hciconfig hci0 up` before, it was one of the non-working solutions I have found, it doesn't work. I suggest to even remove that to avoid confusion for anyone trying to find a new solution.

Comment: Ah fixed! I was taking a look a the commands mentioned in the Arch Wiki, specialy `hciconfig -a`, and noticed that `hci0` is the controller built in to my notebook, `hci1` is the one that I attach to the usb. So the commands should be applied to this one, and `sudo hciconfig hci1 up` works to power it. I suggest to document about this in your answer.

Comment: Likely, the minimum recipe is: 1. `hciconfig -a` to list the controllers; 2. Identify the plugged one; 3. Power it up with `sudo hciconfig hciX up` (`bluetoothctl` can be used to `show` power status); 4. Automate with udev.

Comment: I primarily use a desktop and the thought of a built-in controller never occurred to me (: